# Sql Query get summary count

Tags: sql, oracle, select, group-by, count

I have below table in Oracle

```
Fruit  | Color
-------+-------
Apple  | Red
Apple  | Green
Cherry | Red
```

I need below summary, only those which have different colors

```
Fruit | Colors
------+-------
Apple | 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use aggregation, with a filter in the `having` clause:

```
select fruit, count(*) colors
from mytable
group by fruit
having count(*) > 1
```

This assumes no duplicates on `(fruit, color)`, as shown in your sample data. Else, you need `count(distinct color)` instead of `count(*)`:

```
select fruit, count(distinct color) colors
from mytable
group by fruit
having count(distinct color) > 1
```

Comment: Little twist.. Can we get output like below.. (Column Header) Fruit| Red | Green | Black.. (Row 1) Apple | 1 | 1 | 0

Answer (score 2):

This is a `group by` that filters on the result of the aggregate:

```
select fruit, count(distinct color) as colors
from the_table
group by fruit
having count(distinct color) > 1;
```

The `distinct` in `count(distinct color)` makes it only count the *different* colors for each fruit.